# Customize states

Tags: tfs

We are trying customize Kanban board with new columns and new states. Couldn't find an option to customize states other than modifying XML template. Is there any other way to add customized states?

Answer (score 0):

In TFS 2017? No.

In Azure DevOps Server (formerly known as TFS) 2019? Yes -- the XML work item process model is still supported, but a new inheritance model is also introduced.